# Unity: Counting Collected Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an object-collecting game in Unity/C#. I've got two scripts that control this, **GameController** and **Eggs**. My problem is that although I've set the default number of eggs to 1 (I will make the number higher later), this doesn't reflect in my GameController's eggsLeft tally: It starts and stays at 0. Collecting/destroying an egg doesn't affect the number either. I'm very new to programming (less than a month!) and am wondering where I've gone wrong.

**GameController** script:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour{
    public int eggsLeft = 1;
    public bool collectedAll = false;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (eggsLeft <= 0)
        {
            collectedAll = true;
        }
        else collectedAll = false;
    }
}
```

**Eggs** script:

```
public class Eggs : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameController gc;

    void Start()
    {
        gc = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<GameController>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        gc.eggsLeft--;
    }
}
```

Comment: While im no expert with unity, i ll try to help you. If you on the update of your game controller set the eggsLeft to 3, does it update your GameController Tally? . Another thing is you dont need the else, collectAll = false. Since it creates as false, and stay that way until its true

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I changed the eggsLeft to 3 in the GameController script... But it still shows up as zero in Unity's inspector...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific reason your solution isn't working is because and integer is a value type. In your Egg class, we you are doing `gc.eggsLeft--` you're getting the value of the egg, and then subtracting one ... but you're not reassigning that value back again to the variable.

To make things a little clearer, we can strengthen your code by doing the following:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int eggsLeft = 1;

    public bool collectedAll
    {
        get { return eggsLeft == 0; }
    }

    public void CollectEgg ( )
    {
        if ( eggsLeft > 0 ) eggsLeft--;
    }
}


public class Eggs : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameController gc;

    void Start ( )
    {
        gc = FindObjectOfType<GameController> ( );
        if ( !gc ) Debug.LogError ( "Could not find a GameController!" );
    }

    void OnMouseDown ( )
    {
        Destroy ( gameObject );
        gc.CollectEgg ( );
    }
}
```

Notice now that `collectedAll` is only worked out when you query that property. And the answer is worked out by seeing if the value of `eggsLeft` is zero.

This then means that the `Egg` class doesn't need to worry about the maths going on in the GameController. It simply let's the GameController know an egg was collected, and then leaves it at that.

Comment: It might also be helpful to research 'Value' types vs 'Reference' types.  That will help you a loooot over time.
Good luck!

Comment: That code is much more elegant - thank you! I will look into the Value / Reference types; I'm glad for the tip!

Comment: @Volantix if it's worked out for you, it's helpful to mark the response as the answer. Cheers.